# Why does this HTML break bootstrap's tabbed layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The following code snippet is taken from the Bootstrap 3 website's example code for tabs, and it works exactly as it should:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tab 1</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Tab 2</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Tab 3</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Tab 4</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Now, if I add the following collection of nested tags into the content of the first tab pane:

```
<h4><div><h4><h5></h5></h4></div></h4>
```

... suddenly the tabbed layout breaks and the content of all four tabs can be seen at once. (At least, in Chrome - I haven't tested this in other browsers yet). Take a look at the following example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tab 1<h4><div><h4><h5></h5></h4></div></h4></div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Tab 2</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Tab 3</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">Tab 4</div>
</div>

</div>
```

What is going on here? I have to assume this is a bug in Bootstrap, or Jquery, or the browser... am I right?

Comment: Where have I nested a block element inside an inline element?

Comment: To be clear, I'm aware that this is bad markup. My question is, why does that *exact* chunk of HTML break the bootstrap tabs?

This happened on a site where users can use HTML on their profile biographies, which is then sanitized before display. For some reason a user's profile was breaking the tabbed layout, and I was able to narrow it down to this particular sequence of nested tags.

Comment: @Martin - It's hard to consider this a bug in bootstrap, since it's cause by some nesting that is highly unconventional, and probably would not pass W3C validation.  It seems odd you want nested heading tags, with a div rolled up in there.  Was this an accidental discovery, or intentional?

Comment: @cale_b thanks, that's helpful. Yes, this was very much accidental, the result of a user putting some bad HTML in their biography field. I suspect the only solution will be to sanitize the user input better.

Comment: Ah, user entry strikes again.  Happens all the time! Good luck.

Comment: Bootstrap would have css written with couple of selectors for EG; `.container ~ .nav.nav-tabs li` and some css to this. Now if you wrap the ul tags inside a div the css will break, So your HTML must also obey the bootstrap conventions.